# Why is origin/master behind in commits?

Tags: git, github

I am writing a small automation script, that is supposed to push code to my remote GitHub repository.

I use the following URL format `https://{username}:{password}@github.com/{owner}/{repo}`, while the new changes are reflected on the remote master branch, my local (?) `origin/master` gets behind with its commit.

If I manually push again using `git push origin master` the status is good again, even though no changes are being applied to my remote repository. Within my config file I have my remote origin set to `https://github.com/{owner}/{repo}`.

Do I need to change my remote origin configuration for my approach to work or is there some update call I can make, that resolves this issue?

Comment: Did you type `git push origin/master` literally, and it worked, or was it rather `git push origin master`?

Comment: sorry I meant git push origin master

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to change my remote origin configuration for my approach to work

Yes and no (for some value of "work" anyway—it actually *is* working, after all, it's just not working the way you'd *like*).  There are multiple ways to deal with this.

In particular:

> I [have an] automation script ... [that uses] the following URL format `https://{username}:{password}@github.com/{owner}/{repo}`

In other words, this script runs:

```
git push https://{username}:{password}@github.com/{owner}/{repo} master
```

and not:

```
git push origin master
```

> while the new changes are reflected on the remote master branch, my local (?) origin/master gets behind with its commit.

That's because Git has no idea that this raw URL means the same thing as `origin`.

> If I manually push again using `git push origin master` the status is good again ...

That's because your Git now calls up the Git at `origin`, using the (probably different)<sup>1</sup> URL for `origin`, and *asks* that Git about its branch names.  This web-based "phone call" lets them talk to each other.  The other Git says *my `master` is commit `a123456...`* which is the commit you pushed a moment ago.  Your Git says: *Hey, I have `a123456`!  I'll fix up my `origin/master` to remember that you do too.*  Meanwhile your Git tells their Git: *Oh, OK, I have nothing new for you* and they politely hang up the phone call and get back to their everyday work (for their Git, go back to sleep; for yours, do some housekeeping).

By contacting them using the *name* `master`, you get your remote-tracking name, `origin/master`, updated.  By contacting them using any other name—or a raw URL—you don't.

Thus, you can fix your problem by:

- doing the push with the name `origin`, so that your Git updates your `origin/master`, or
- re-contacting them—e.g., running `git fetch origin master`—after doing the push with the password-y URL that doesn't match.

With `git fetch`, your Git will ask their Git about all their branches (the default if you don't say `master`) or their `master` (`git fetch origin/master`).  Then your Git will bring over any commits they have that you don't, and update your remote-tracking names (all, if you got all, or just `origin/master`, if you got just stuff from their `master`).

Fetch and push *both* update your remote-tracking names if and when they can, based on the (somewhat limited in some cases) information your Git got from their Git.

If you want to do all this without a separate step, but with a temporary URL associated with the name `origin`, you can use:

```
git -c remote.origin.pushurl={url} push origin master
```

(The reason to use `pushurl` here is in case you actually have a pushurl specified.  If not, `git -c remote.origin.url=...` would suffice.)

(Note that using a cleartext password, regardless of whether you do it as a raw URL in a `git push` command, or via `git -c`, is generally a bad idea.  Consider generating and using an authentication token instead: https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line.  The token is still security-sensitive: the main difference here is that you can continue to keep the password secret while revoking the authentication token.)

---

<sup>1</sup>If the URL is spelled precisely the same, Git could (but doesn't) notice that `remote.origin.url` or `remote.origin.pushurl` matches the one given on the command line.  But if there's even a single character different ... well, Git doesn't really parse URLs to the last character, it just identifies which scheme you're using (`git://` vs `https://` for instance) and then, for HTTP, passes the rest of the job off to the CURL libraries.  So Git could be sure about exact-same-spelling but not about anything else.  As it is, Git doesn't even bother.

Comment: git -c remote.origin.pushurl={url} push origin master was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for your detailed explanation. I also removed the clear text password in favor of the token. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

- List your existing remotes in order to get the name of the remote you want to change.

  `$ git remote -v`

You will get origin for example:

> origin  git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (fetch)
>
> origin  git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (push)

- Change your remote's URL from SSH to HTTPS with the git remote set-url command.

  `$ git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git`